# Azure Cosmos Session consistency Vs Bounded staleness consistency for microservices with multiple instances in same region

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Suppose I am developing a social media app. We have multiple instances of backend service deployed in the same region. Now, whenever the app page is reloaded, one of the instances of backend service will receive the request and contact cosmos. The problem is follows -:

T1 - App page loaded. Instance 1 of service issued read request to cosmos.

T2 - Comment added by user A. Instance 2 of service issued a write in cosmos.

T3 - App page again loaded. Instance 3 of service issued read request to cosmos.

If we use session consistency, the session token for time T2 and T3 will be different as write query is issued by a different instance and read query by a different one. Due to this, it may happen that at time T3, when the app page is loaded, the comment added by user A is not loaded as session consistency dilutes to consistent-prefix in case of different session tokens in same region.

To solve this, we can use bounded staleness but I think it may be an overkill.

How can we handle these multi-instance service scenarios with session consistency?

Comment: It's not clear what your specific goal is. Distributed instances of anything always require some time to converge on state changes. If you can't tolerate different views within the replication window, you'd likely need to avoid distributed state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this with session token is to implement a distributed mutex. While this will work, it may adversely impact performance because the token resource may be locked when their is a high concurrency of requests.

All writes in Cosmos DB are majority quorum (3/4 replicas). For accounts with just a single region, Bounded staleness ensures no stale reads by doing a 2 replica read, then comparing the LSN from each replica. If the LSN's match, the data is the latest and it returns to the client. If the LSN's do not match, it returns the higher one because this will be the latest.

The trade off here between doing a distributed mutex and using bounded staleness is building a distributed mutex takes time and effort and can adversely impact latency. Using Bounded Staleness requires zero effort, but every read costs 2x that of Session because it is a 2 replica read, rather than a single replica with Session consistency.

Comment: Thanks @mark for the answer. So, basically, we have to share the session by some mechanism among the service instances.

Comment: exactly. This is certainly possible. Reliable Collections in Service Fabric. Durable Entities in Functions, etc. You can even write your own using a Cosmos account with strong consistency.

Comment: Hey @mark, I have one more doubt. You mentioned in brief in your answer about how reading 2 replicas achieves strong consistency. I was reading the docs. It is written that in case of eventual and consistent prefix consistencies, there is a single replica read. I understand how eventual consistency can be achieved by single replica read. But I am not able to understand how consistent prefix can be guaranteed by single replica read. I suppose there has to be some condition in case of reading like from where to read or during write, like which all replicas to write to. Can you explain in brief ?

Comment: Eventual consistency has nothing to do with single replica reads. ALL data is written to three replicas when committed. Consistency model governs replication. Eventual consistency means data is "eventually" consistent, Consistent Prefix means data is always read in the order it was written. Single replica reads cannot guarantee non-stale reads because they may read from a replica which has not had the latest committed data written to it.

Comment: hmm, when we use consistency prefix, we use local majority to commit the data. Now, suppose that the 4th replica was not able to write message. But still user's write is successful. So, when the user writes second data, the second data may land to the 4th replica which does not have first data. In eventual consistency, this is fine. But in consistent prefix, this is not. So, I think you may have some conditional logic during writing to select replicas. I am talking about one replica set within one region itself.